# Geany: Can we open a website link from geany text editor?

Tags: geany, geany-plugin

I am a big fan of Geany text editor. I am using it to write Python, C and as a simple text editor.

My question is following:

Suppose I have opened a file example.txt and it contains:

```
https://www.youtube.com/  
www.youtube.com
```

Is there any way I can select this text code and open from any browser?
Is there any plugin or any workaround that I can open the given link directly in a web browser (let's say firefox)
from the Geany text editor?

My intitial attempt is like this:

```
Edit > Format > Send Selection to > Set Custom Commands > firefox
Edit > Preferences > Keybindings > Send to Custom Command 1 > primary 1
```

Then, I did following steps:

```
selected the text "https://www.youtube.com/"
then press ctrl 1
then, the text "https://www.youtube.com/" vanishes
and, empty firefox is opened
```

Note that, however, if I type `firefox https://www.youtube.com &`
This opens youtube without any error.

My question is can we do something that if I select the text and ctrl 1 opens the same website.

Some related links are following:
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/312677/how-to-set-custom-commands-in-geany?rq=1
http://www.geany.org/manual/#sending-text-through-custom-commands

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/528367/shortcut-to-send-selection-to-terminal-in-geany send to custom(browser) could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a context action. See https://www.geany.org/manual/#context-actions

> Preferences -> Tools -> Contextaction

firefox %s

opens the selected Text

Right-click or define a keybinding for executing this context action.

Answer (score 0):

I did following to open a link:
suppose the link is : www.youtube.com

then,
firefox www.youtube.com
select the line
right click, Edit > send selection to terminal > hit enter

Or, we can set keybindings for these:

```
Edit > Preferences > keybindings
Select Current Line(s) = shift alt L
Send selection to terminal = shift alt T
```

Usage:

```
firefox www.youtube.com
select this line: shift alt L
send to terminal: shift alt T
go to terminal  : F4
run command     : Enter
```

Another Example:

```
www.youtube.com
select this line: shift alt L
send to terminal: shift alt T
go to terminal  : F4
go to beginning : ctrl A
add a command   : firefox 
run command     : Enter
```